# Error control in constructors

Tags: c++

There is such class:

```
class Circle{
  int x;
  int y;
  int radius;
public:
  Circle(int x_, int y_, int radius_){
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
    if(radius < 0)
      signal error;
    radius = radius_;
  }
};
```

It is not possible to create circle with radius less than zero. What is a good method to signal error in constructor? I know that there are exceptions, but are there any other methods?

Comment: How about making the radius an unsigned integer so this cannot happen?

Comment: @Kerrek, that will worsen the situation. If warning is ignored from signed to unsigned then, a huge address circle will be created.

Comment: @iammilind: If you ignore warnings, it's your own dumb fault.

Comment: Is it a circle valid with radius exactly zero? Would it be reasonable to simply take the absolute value of a negative radius?

Comment: @iammilind: What is a "huge address circle"?

Comment: @scdmb: Note that it is more common to postfix _private member variables_ with an underscore, like so: `class Foo { ... private: int x_, y_; };` .

Comment: @phresnel, sorry it was a typo; now I can't edit 'address'->'radius' (due to negative value to unsigned; not necessarily huge though).

Comment: @scdmb: just a note, the answer you just selected as solution (Konrad's answer) is technically incorrect. And it's very dangerous advice. So it is a disservice to others to select it as solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good method is not to allow the error to compile!

Unfortunately, merely using `unsigned` will **not** prevent a negative value from being passed to the constructor – it will just be converted implicitly to an `unsigned` value, thus hiding the error (as Alf pointed out in a comment).

The “proper” solution would be to write a custom `nonnegative` (or more generally, `constrained_value`) type to *make* the compiler catch this error – but for some projects this may be too much overhead, since it can easily lead to a proliferation of types. Since it improves (compile-time) type safety, I still think that this is fundamentally the right approach.

A simple implementation of such a constrained type would look as follows:

```
struct nonnegative {
    nonnegative() = default;
    template <typename T,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type>
    nonnegative(T value) : value{value} {}

    operator unsigned () const { return value; }

private:
    unsigned value;
};
```

[See it in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5882940fc737ebeb)

This prevents construction from anything but an unsigned type. In other words, it simply disables the usual implicit, lossy conversion from `signed` to `unsigned` numbers.

If the error cannot be caught at compile time (because the value is received from the user), something like exceptions are the next best solution in most cases (although an alternative is to use an `option` type or something similar).

Often you would encapsulate this throwing of an exception in some kind of `ASSERT` macro. In any case, user input validation should not happen inside a class’ constructor but immediately after the value has been read from the outside world. In C++, the most common strategy is to rely on formatted input:

```
unsigned value;
if (! (std::cin >> value))
    // handle user input error, e.g. throw an exception.
```

Comment: Worth noting that this strategy requires warning on implicit signed-to-unsigned conversion, and likely making warnings errors too. This may be worthwhile, or might be impossible due to codebase cruft.

Comment: @iammilind: Also, the `radius` property should be unsigned as well.

Comment: -1 for advice about using `unsigned`. that will tend to hide the error rather than catch it. c++ guarantees that negative actual arguments will compile and will not cause any trap. that said, the other answers about using exception are not much better. the proper thing to do here is to use an `assert`, not exceptions.

Comment: @Alf That’s your fault for not using warnings. A modern C++ compiler with the warning level cranked up will *not* allow such code. And plain C `assert`s are good for debugging (I almost mentioned that in my answer) but **not** for production code. Production-code asserts must ultimately be implemented via exceptions.

Comment: @Konrad: if it doesn't allow the code, then it is NON-CONFORMING, in breach of the C++ standard. what you say about modern C++ compilers is, happily, totally incorrect. they all follow the standard here, unless you force them to do otherwise.

Comment: @Alf Well, f***. I’ve wrongfully extrapolated from signed/unsigned comparison. Well, sometimes C++ just plain sucks.

Comment: Well, the important point is that the client code should also be using correct types and correct logic. If there's a situation where a negative value might be considered for the radius, then that's worrying.

Comment: Geesh, a 100k+ that doesn't understand what "unsigned" means in C++... this is sort of depressing... :-( .. -1 anyway because this answer is horrible (suggesting unsigned)

Comment: @Alf: But if the radius can be negative from unpredictable input, an `assert` alone won't help. Of course this should be caught at the point before the negativity happens, but then we could also just skip exceptions totally for things that don't have to do with system resources. Often enough, in the real world, exceptions _are_ just in case.

Comment: @6502 100k+ is no protection against ignorance. And in particular since I don’t know C (I’m assuming that `unsigned` behaviour is due to backwards compatibility) – and have never pretended to –  I clearly still don’t know all nooks and crannies of C++. (Also, notice how the answer doesn’t suggest using `unsigned` any more.)

Comment: @Kornrad: you should not put too much emphasis on the name "unsigned" and the english meaning you can give to it. What it counts are the language rules and those are NOT of an integer that cannot be negative. The rules are about modulo arithmetic and nothing else... probably a better name would have been "bitmask" (and I hope you don't want to say that the radius of a circle should be a bitmask). In case you wonder... yes, one of C++ mistakes is that an unsigned type (size_t) has been used for container sizes and has nothing to do with the logical idea of non-negative (it dates back to 16-bit)

Comment: @6502 I’d argue that the error wasn’t making `size_t` (or generally, size types) an unsigned type, it was making `unsigned` unchecked. C++’ type system for built-in conversions is far too lenient (and yes, I realise that this is a direct consequence of its C compatibility aims).

Comment: @Komrad: ok, I would like to remove the -1 but somehow broken SO rules (or just broken implementation of them) doesn't allow me to.

Comment: @6502: If you would have looked at the error message, you would know why you can't upvote anymore ;)

Comment: @6502 Never mind, I’d delete the answer but I can’t as long as it’s accepted.

Comment: @Komrad: `unsigned` was there before. It was used for sizes because in the 16-bit epoch it was considered that 32k was a lot less than 64k. This was IMO an error because if 32k is not enough for you then pretty soon 64k won't be enough either; one single bit of precision isn't going to save the day. Using unsigned would have been a great move if unsigned type semantic was the correct one, but it's not (for example the difference of two unsigned is unsigned!).

Comment: @phresnel: I think there has been some racing condition because i downvoted the post when was suggesting unsigned (or this is what I had on the screen when I pressed the button) but now I cannot remove the downvote unless it is edited (even if it's NOT suggesting unsigned any more and it's different from the one that I downvoted). The error message is clear, and clearly says that this SO "feature" has not been designed/implemented correctly.

Comment: -1 The answer just hides the problem by focusing on the example of the circle. If you rely on the "constrained_value" type, you're not answering the question. Because then, what happens when the constrained_value class is given a negative number? The issue here is we have bad data. We can't fix bad data at compile time. No matter how you shuffle your types, some structure at some point is going to receive information it can't build a valid construct out of, and we have to figure out how to deal with this. 

In my opinion, this is what exceptions are for.

Comment: @Kian You are wrong, but in an interesting way. The idea is to forbid the `constrained_type` from being constructed with types which may hold invalid values. In OP’s example, this would mean deleting the constructor which accepts `signed int`. That way, if the programmer *tries* to instantiate the type with a non-unsigned value, the compiler catches this behaviour. [Here’s a running example of that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5882940fc737ebeb). Would it help if I added that to the answer?

Comment: @Kian Incidentally, you are of course right in that when we deal with user input, we have to perform runtime validation *at some point*. However, this should happen as soon as possible, i.e. at the time of input, rather than later at usage. We simply don’t accept any negative number as user input by reading the number directly into an `unsigned` type, and rejecting other values. This is the same logic which compels us to use e.g. `unsigned x; std::cin >> x;` rather than `std::string x; std::cin >> x;` (and then converting from `string` to `unsigned int` at the point of usage).

Comment: @KonradRudolph But you see, you are repeating the problem here. When you write the value into an unsigned integer, that doesn't prevent the user from inputting -1. It just turns that -1 into INT_MAX. Your program is still misbehaving, but in a different way. You don't have an "invalid" object, perhaps, but you don't have an useful one either.
In an interactive program validating inputs is easy. Just don't let the user continue until they get it right. If they input -1, you tell them to try again with a positive value. But in a batch program, the situation is different.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If you have a configuration file, for example, with a -1 where a positive value is expected, you can't just convert it to unsigned and act as if nothing had happened. I'd even say changing the type to modify data is worse. It doesn't matter when you validate; when you hand an invalid value to the constructor of any of your objects, be it circle receiving -1, or constrained_value receiving -1, you need to signal the error because at that point your program already failed. The output of your program can not be what you want it to be. Throw and let someone fix it.

Comment: @Kian You’re wrong there: in my `cin` example, if the user enters -1, then the input stream goes into a fail state. See my updated answer for details. And the situation is *identical* when dealing with batch jobs or configuration files – all of these constitute input from the outside, and thus potentially invalid. The important part is that your approach is to signal the error in the wrong place – the constructor of `circle`, which the outside world knows nothing about. To reiterate: input validation should happen *as soon as possible*. And that is only possible by using strong types.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, wasn't sure about cin, seems I was indeed wrong there. I agree that input validation should be done as soon as possible. My point wasn't that Circle specifically has to throw, but that when constructing an object with data that would set it to an invalid state, you have to signal the error in the constructor. In some cases, like your nonnegative type, you can find the error as soon as the data is entered.

Comment: @KonradRudolph For a more complex type, however, even if the types are right the values might be problematic. At the point where you have enough information to determine if your data is good, you have the data you need to construct the object. So rather than creating a function that will check if your data is good, and raise an error if it isn't, put that logic in the constructor itself and throw on bad data. Because someone, at some point, is going to forget to put the checking code, but they can't avoid the constructor.

Answer (score 7):

No. Throw an exception — that is the standard way to bail out from the ctor.

Comment: Yes, throwing an exception is best, but the question is "are there other methods". I think Luchian pointed out a decent one.

Comment: And you should always be suspicious for such questions Owen, because often they root in the ridiculous "exceptions are too slow" reason ...

Comment: @Owen: That method does not signal an error in a constructor, it just delays the problem until it's not in a constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Throw an exception. That's what [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) is all about.

Answer (score 2):

Exception is the best method to report an error from constructor in C++. It is much safe and clear than all others methods. If an error occures in constructor, the object should not be created. Throwing exception is the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Exception is the correct way to signal the error. Because, passing a negative value as a radius is a logical mistake.
It's [safe to `throw` from constructor](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#ctor-exceptions).

As other option, you can print an error message into a log file.

Third option is somewhat suggested by @Luchian; I am rephrasing it.

> Don't call the constructor, if the radius it < 0. You should have a
>   check outside the object creation.

Edit: there is a logical error in your code:

```
if(radius < 0)  // should be 'radius_'
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion is that you should use `throw std::runtime_error` in the general case, and as UncleBens points out in comments, `invalid_argument` in this case.

In some circumstances, like when it is guaranteed that the radius can't be negative by means of unpredictable input, you should use `assert` instead, because then it is a programmer error (== bug):

```
#include <cassert>

...
    assert (radius >= 0);
```

This disables the check for release builds.

A third alternative would be to use your own datatype that guarantees as a post-condition that it's never less than 0; though one has to be careful not to invent too many micro-types:

```
template <typename Scalar, bool ThrowRuntimeError>
class Radius {
public:
    Radius (Scalar const &radius) : radius_(radius) {
        assert (radius>=Scalar(0));
        if (ThrowRuntimeError) {
            if (Scalar(0) >= radius) throw std::runtime_error("can't be negative");
        }
    }

    ...

private:
    Radius(); // = delete;

    Scalar radius_;
};
```

Note that in such general implementations, one must be careful to avoid compiler warnings that warn about unneeded comparisons against zero (e.g. when `Scalar = unsigned int`).

Anyways, I'd go without the Radius class, and use assertations (if negative radius can only be a bug) or exceptions (if negative radius can be the result of bad input).

Comment: I'd throw `std::invalid_argument` (derived from `std::logic_error`) which seems to be more likely the correct category for the problem :)

Comment: @Raedwald: Why not `invalid_argument`, which is a specialisation of `logic_error`?

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach for error in constructors is using an exception.

However an alternative that is sometime useful is the "zombie" approach. In other words if you cannot construct a working object properly then create an object that is non-functional but that can be tested for this and that can be destroyed safely. All the methods should also fail gracefully and become NOPs.

Most of the times this approach is just an annoyance because you will **delay** the discovery of a problem to when the object is actually used... but it is a viable path if you have serious reasons for avoiding exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the radius in a init() method which you call after the constructor.

Comment: No, that's a terrible idea, and I downvoted. A constructed object is expected to be done and ready to use.

Comment: You can call any practice stupid or error-prone if you don't do it right.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You can't forget to call ctor, or call it twice on the same object. You can forget to call `init`, or whatever. Not to mention the object is in undefined state between construction and `init`. Object construction should be done entirely in the ctor — that's the whole point of them.

Comment: I wouldn't call this idea terrible. What if the error isn't part of the consistency of the object? At any rate it's certainly a *possible* way to do it.

Comment: @Owen: If the error isn't part of the object's invariants, then it's not really an error, is it? This idea is just wrong.

Comment: Thank you. It's just an option. If you think in absolute terms (NEVER do that, or ALWAYS do it like this), you're probably going to run into trouble sooner or later. Different problems call for different solutions. Try to keep an open mind...

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: but then the different solution should be really better, in what way is this better ?

Comment: @Luchian: Always validate your input. Always release your resources. Never access memory you don't own. Never attempt to free memory twice. Need I go on?

Comment: :)) How else are you supposed to hack then?

Comment: "You can call any practice stupid or error-prone if you don't do it right." -> Like not using C++ the raiight way?

Comment: Not against its rules in the sense that this gives not well-formed code, but against common practice to make your class hard to use wrong, and easy to use right. And why would an `init()` method be safer? A Circle with negative radius should never be born.

Comment: @Luchian: intentionally making your code more fragile, and making it harder to use your class correctly for no reason? Yeah, I'd say so. In so far as C++ *has* rules, "don't be stupid", and "don't write bad code" should be considered to be among them.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786853/why-use-an-initialization-method-instead-of-a-constructor, lots of good reasons given there.

Comment: And which of those applies here? Have you also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786853/why-use-an-initialization-method-instead-of-a-constructor/3786967#3786967 ?

Comment: @Luchian: That question doesn't give lots of good reasons. It gives a few very bad reasons.

Comment: I have - "Yes I can think of several, but generally it's not a good idea.". All I'm saying is this isn't a "DON'T EVER DO IT" topic.

Comment: @DeadMG Well say my object represents a db con and for some (not so good) reason makes a query in the ctor and it fails -- but the connection is intact. Now you would say that code should never have been in the ctor in the first place and you'd be right. But I think it's worth opening the question that you might initially put something in the ctor and later realize it shouldn't be there. But no you're right -- this case belongs in the ctor.

Comment: @Luchian: a class that can be brought into an inconsistent state is broken. ALWAYS. No exceptions. A circle which doesn't have a radius is broken. ALWAYS. And a Circle class which allows you to define a circle with no radius is broken. ALWAYS. The language tries to protect you from creating such classes (by forcing you to throw an exception if an error is discovered during construction), and circumventing it by creating a secondary `init()` function doesn't solve the problem, it just works around the checks built into the language to enforce sane class design.

Comment: Agreed. The unsigned int answer is much better. Throwing an exception is much better - however the poster asked for something other than an exception and I only made a suggestion. Right?

Comment: "I know that there are exceptions, but are there any other methods?"

Comment: "Usually you have to put all sensitive code outside the constructor. " -> That is really not the usual way to go. It yields broken or incomplete (which is equivalent to broken) objects, as @jalf points out.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly to C++ - no... Exceptions are the only one 'good' way...

However there are many other 'less-standard' approaches, I recommend two-phase constructors(used in symbian).

Comment: Can you elaborate on two-phase constructors?

Comment: There is a lot of info about this in the net. The general idea is to contruct the object (by using new), and then call init() on this object... The constructor itself only "starts" the object, in a "zero" state, then the call to init() do the real allocation/initiation job. Please google for "two phase constructor"

Comment: Usually, answers on StackOverflow should be self-contained to a sane degree, which is why your answer is not as good as it could/should be. The googling itself is really not the problem, I did already.

Answer (score 0):

Just another possibility to add to what's already here: you could mimic what people do in ML-ish languages and make a "smart constructor":

```
Circle* makeCircle(...) { ... }
```

that may return NULL.

Though I agree throwing an exception is probably want you want here.

Comment: While this is indeed another possibility, I just want to add to this that this would play against "hard to use wrong, easy to use right" -> client may forget to delete, client may dereference an invalid address, client may accidentally assign to the pointer.