# Derived types and extended types construction

Tags: oop, fortran, abstract, extend, fortran2003

I am quite new to Fortran OOP and I am facing some issues at initializing parent and derived types. I have one module containing the parent type `object` (sorry for the overuse of the word..) and its derived type `circle`, which has the extra `radius` field.

The way I need to initialize the `object` type now requires to use a dummy argument for radius, which I would like to avoid. So at the moment what I have works, but I would like to know a fancier way to do this since it does not seem very practical if I need to have further derived types from `object` in the future.

I guess that using `object` as an abstract parent type would help in this sense? Or using generic procedures, but I don't really know how to do that.

The code is below.

```
module objectMod
  implicit none

  type :: object
     real,allocatable   :: x(:,:)           ! position vector (points) --- (M,{i,j})
     real               :: centre(2)        ! centre of the object
     integer            :: M=50             ! number of Lagrangian points of the object (default)
     real               :: eps=0.1          ! kernel of the surface (default)
   contains
     procedure :: init=>init_object
  end type object

contains

  subroutine init_object(a,centre,radius,M,eps)
    implicit none

    class(object),intent(inout)   :: a
    real,intent(in)               :: centre(2)
    integer,intent(in),optional   :: M
    real,intent(in),optional      :: eps
    real,intent(in),optional      :: radius ! ignored for object

    if(present(M)) a%M = M
    if(.not.allocated(a%x)) allocate(a%x(a%M,2))
    a%centre = centre
    if(present(eps)) a%eps = eps
  end subroutine init_object
end module objectMod

module geomMod
  use objectMod
  implicit none
  real,parameter :: PI = 3.14159265

  type,extends(object) :: circle
     real              :: radius    ! radius
   contains
     procedure :: init=>init_circle
  end type circle

contains

  subroutine init_circle(a,centre,radius,M,eps)
    implicit none
    class(circle),intent(inout) :: a
    real,intent(in)             :: centre(2)
    real,intent(in),optional    :: radius
    integer,intent(in),optional :: M
    real,intent(in),optional    :: eps

    integer :: i
    real    :: dtheta

    ! object type attributes initialization
    a%centre = centre
    if(present(M)) a%M = M
    if(.not.allocated(a%x)) allocate(a%x(a%M,2))
    if(present(eps)) a%eps = eps
    ! circle type attributes initialization
    a%radius = radius

    dtheta = 2.*PI/real(a%M-1)
    do i = 1,a%M
      a%x(i,1) = a%radius*cos(dtheta*(i-1))+a%centre(1)
      a%x(i,2) = a%radius*sin(dtheta*(i-1))+a%centre(2)
    end do
  end subroutine init_circle
end module geomMod
```

Comment: I cannot drop radius because then I get an arguments mismatch error (obviously I have tried that). By fancier I mean a way of not needing dummy arguments for the parent constructor since it will get nasty as I add more and more extended types of "object". And sometimes I will need to instantiate "object".

Comment: I actually used that source to code this. Search in there "ignored for shape" as that's the part of the code that I am actually using and which requires to use dummy arguments for parent derived types.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are doing is to create constructors as type-bound procedures. The requirement, that the argument list must conform is against you.

Type-bound procedures are simply not the right tool for constructors (or initializers).

In Fortran we use functions returning an instance of the object to initialize it.

```
function init_object(centre,M,eps) result(a)
  type(object) :: a
  real,intent(in)               :: centre(2)
  integer,intent(in),optional   :: M
  real,intent(in),optional      :: eps
  !NO radius
end function init_object


interface object
  procedure init_object
end interface



....



obj = object(my_centre, my_m, my_eps)
```

This is also how the default structure constructors are called.

---

I see you took the example from some online tutorial. I find the example to be a poor design. If you disagree, you will have to live with these problems it brings.

---

So, basically, you want an initializer method instead of a constructor (see [Why use an initialization method instead of a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786853/why-use-an-initialization-method-instead-of-a-constructor) for some discussion. Objective-C uses something like that https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/objectivec-lesson-11-object-initialization/76 but more recent Swift uses constructors instead.).

You could employ generics in this way:

```
    module types

        type t1
          integer :: i
        contains
          generic :: init => init_t1
          procedure, private :: init_t1
        end type

        type, extends(t1) :: t2
          integer :: j
        contains
          generic :: init => init_t2
          procedure, private :: init_t2
        end type

        type, extends(t2) :: t3
          integer :: k
        contains
          generic :: init => init_t3
          procedure, private :: init_t3
        end type

    contains


      subroutine init_t1(self, i)
        class(t1) :: self
      end subroutine

      subroutine init_t2(self, i, j)
        class(t2) :: self
      end subroutine

      subroutine init_t3(self, i, j, k)
        class(t3) :: self
      end subroutine

    end module
```

In my opinion this is plain ugly and un-Fortranic, but it does what you want.

You will have to make special care that the user will not call a wrong version inadvertently by overloading it by something that will issue an error message.

My advice is still to rather follow common patterns rather than invent your own ways which will confuse those who are used to the mainstream.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Vladimir-F . I would like to have them as type-bound procedures, so I guess that the best thing to do would be to set 'object' as abstract parent type. But then I won't be able to use 'object' itself in the main program, right?

Comment: I can't see any reason for the abstract type. And definitely no reason that would have any connection with my answer. Please read it again *"If you really wan't to use type-bound procedures anyway, you can, but you cannot have one universal %init(), you must use a different name for each type and probably you should make them non-overridable."*

Comment: BTW can I ask for the reason to have them as type-bound procedures? I cant find any. Remember that in Java or C++ or similar people also use functions that return the object (or a reference to it).

Comment: I have read and understood your answer. I could do that (use different names for different types) but I want to use the same `init` procedure for every `object` or extended type  such as `circle` since from a user point of view (people who will set up the main file) is better to have a single procedure name to initialize any `object` or derived types.

Comment: Yes, I would like an initializer instead of a constructor. I will give that a try, but I agree that it looks a bit weird. Anyway, I think that using an abstract parent would make things easier.