# Forcing a subclass to provide an initialization method

Tags: java, oop, types, constructor, abstract

Is it a good practice to provide an abstract method to help the developer to initialize a complex object in the superclass constructor?

Consider the following classes:

```
// Parent class
abstract public class A() {
    protected Person[] people;

    public A(Person[] people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    abstract protected Person[] initPeople();
}

// Child class
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(initPeople());
    }

    @Override
    protected Person[] initPeople() {
        return new Person[] {
            new Person("James"),
            new Person("Mary"),
            new Person("Elizabeth")
        };
    }
}
```

If there was no `initPeople` method, the developer of the child class would probably add it himself because creating the `people` object take several lines.

Is there a better way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Yes: just remove that abstract method, and let the subclass decide how it calls the superclass constructor.

Comment: If you add abstract in the superclass, the subclass must override it. By the way, you must return `Person[]` for the `initPeople` method

Comment: Firstly, your code does not work, `initPeople()` method is void but you are returning the void. 

    @Override
    protected Person[] initPeople() {
        return new Person[] {
            new Person("James"),
            new Person("Mary"),
            new Person("Elizabeth")
        }

Comment: Thank you, I edit the code.

Comment: @Raedwald I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one marked. There is a subtle difference between the two.

Comment: @CKing if they are different, the text of the question should clearly indicate how they are different, with a link to the other question. Edit the question, and let the voters on the Reopen queue decide.

Comment: And another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors

Comment: @Raedwald Unless I missed something, the OP clearly asks *"Is there a better way to do it*" indicating that the question is not about calling `abstract` methods from a constructor but asking for a way to force subclasses to provide an initialization method? The calling of `abstract` method in the constructor is one of the solutions that the OP could think of but that is not the real question here is it?

Comment: Initialization methods are a bad udea anyway. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786967/545127

Comment: @Raedwald What has that got to do with marking this as a duplicate? Something being a bad idea (I don't agree that it's a bad idea but that is off topic) doesn't make it a candidate for a duplicate I am sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem with this approach is that even though the subclass is required to implement the `initPeople` method, there is nothing forcing the subclass to call it in the constructor.

A better approach would be to use the  [Template](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern :

```
public abstract class A 
{
    protected Person[] people;

    public final void execute() 
    {
         initPeople();
         performOperations();
    } 
    protected abstract void initPeople();
    protected abstract void performOperations();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I have a question about it: is it safe to call `execute()` in the constructor of `A`?

Comment: That is not recommended. The purpose of a constructor is to initialize an object and not call methods that perform operations on the data. The idea here is that after instantiating a subclass of `A`, the client will call the `execute` method. The execute method will initialize the person array first through `initPeople` and then call `performOperations`. The way the code is structured, subclasses will always have to provide a way to initialize person and then a way to perform some operations on it.

Comment: why go for a `RuntimeException` instead of an `UnsupportedOperationException` ?

Comment: @FrankK An `UnsupportedOperationException` by definition indicates an optional operation that is not supported; however, in this particular case, `initPeople` is central to the correctness of the `execute` method. If the `people` array is not intialized, none of the subclasses can do their job correctly.

Comment: in that case, why not just make it abstract?

Comment: @FrankK I here you. This answer was typed form my mobile phone. Point taken.